# Reference to member 'default' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Tags: swiftui

This error occurs with this code and I have no idea what it means:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    Alert(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text(alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
```

Any help please.

Comment: Errors in SwiftUI usually don't show where they really are. Please, add code snippet of all the ContentView

Comment: It is likely you didn't place the .alert in the correct place.  You may have added it inside a button label closure for example instead of placing it as a modifier to a button or another view.  Further code would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too and Xcode become messy. What I did to fix in in my end was:

First, create the alert in a computed property:

```
 var alert: Alert {
        Alert(title: Text("Oops"), message: Text("Error Message"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Dismiss")))
    }
```

Then use the alert property at the end of your superview:

```
@State var showAlert = false
 var body: some View {
     ZStack {
             ...
     }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: { self.alert })
 }
```

I hope this solution works for you too.

Answer (score 4):

I had this error message because the brackets (the rounded ones) were not correctly paired. Your code works, these versions also work (using code that is not a "one liner" and Editor/Structure/Re-Indent also helps to see what might be wrong :-) ):

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
    Alert(title: Text("Title"),
          message: Text("An alert"),
          primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
          }),
          secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel"), action: {
          })
    )
}
```

or this:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
    Alert(title: Text("Title"),
          message: Text("An alert"),
          primaryButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
          },
          secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a SwiftUI view I was doing the following:

```
.onReceive {
    .task {
       someCode // ERROR ❌
    }
}
```

And getting the following error:

> Reference to member 'task' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

All I had to do instead was:

```
.onReceive {
    Task {
       someCode ✅
    }
}
```